# Removing spaces from in between sentences.

Tags: c

I have sentences that I would like to strip spaces out of, but I am reading from a text file. Here's a sample of the words:

```
the tree hugged the man
there are many trees
where are the bees
```

so it should be:

```
thetreehuggedtheman
therearemanytrees
wherearethebees
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv []) {

    int i = 0, line = 6;
    char word[100];

    char const* const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName,"r");
    while(line--){
        fgets(word, 100, file);
        i++;
        char *wordRev = reverse(word);

        // Remove spaces from string here



    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "reverse" have to do with removing the spaces?

Answer (score 3):

With use of `strtok` and `sprintf` you can achieve that -

```
char s[100];                                  // destination string
int i=0;
while(fgets(word, 100, file)!=NULL){          // read from file
    memset(s,'\0',sizeof s);                  // initialize (reset) s in every iteration
     char *token=strtok(word," ");            // tokenize string read from file
     while(token!=NULL){                      // check return of strtok         
          while(s[i]!='\0')i++;                  
          sprintf(&s[i],"%s",token);         // append it in s   
          token=strtok(NULL," ");
      }
    printf("%s\n",s);                         // print s
}
```

Controlling loop using `fgets` . Loop will stop as `fgets` `return` `NULL`.

Note that `s` will be modified in each iteration , so copy the modified string to another array if you want to use it later in program.

Comment: Although this might work, it looks rather inefficient. Rather than calling strlen all the time, you should have a pointer keeping track of where in the destination buffer you are writing. Also you need to do `token+1` somewhere if you actually wish to remove the spaces.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah , I got that `strlen` part , and removed that calls . but I don't get `token +1`  .Why would that be for ?

Comment: @Lundin But yes thanks for pointing out , I need to improve  more :-)

Comment: (Nevermind about the token+1 part I was confusing strtok behavior with another function.)

Answer (score 2):

To keep it as simple and generic as possible:

```
void remove_char (char ch, char* dest, const char* source)
{
  while(*source != '\0')
  {
    if(*source != ch)
    {
      *dest = *source;
      dest++;
    }
    source++;
  }

  *dest = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to remove the spaces from lines you can always parse it out:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAXLN 100

void remove_spaces(char line[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int line = 6;
    char word[MAXLN];

    char const* const filename = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (line--) {
        fgets(word, MAXLN, file);
        remove_spaces(word);
    }

    return 0;
}

void remove_spaces(char line[])
{
    char no_spaces[MAXLN];
    for (int i=0, j=0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (line[i] == ' ') continue;
        no_spaces[j++] = line[i];
    }
    no_spaces[j-1] = '\0'
    printf("%s\n", no_spaces);
}
```

Comment: This iterates over 100 characters no matter the actual string length, plus it comes with the memset overhead. Very inefficient.

Comment: What does it matter? Why write needlessly slow code when you can get much faster code with no effort? Profession ethics.

Comment: @Lundin you're right I edited out the inefficient parts.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple function that goes through the array and skips the space character.

```
void rmSpace(char *string)
{
    size_t len = strlen(string) , index = 0;

    for( size_t n = 0 ; n < len ; n++ )
    {
        if( string[n] != ' ' )
        {
            string[index] = string[n];
            index++;
        }
    }
    string[index] = '\0';
}
```